# Combo Seaborn plots don't line up properly

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to overlay a lineplot above a countplot in seaborn. They both work when they are seperated:
[image]

By put together they end up at opposite ends of the chart:
[image]

Does anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the twinx() from matplotlib and your first graph needs to be just matplotlib, not seaborn. I'm not sure why seaborn has a problem with combo charts, but I got the exact same problem as you did. Here's my code with population data from kaggle:

```
#Create bar plot for annual growth by year
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#import dataframe for data
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

#Create combo chart
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
color = 'tab:green'

#bar plot creation
ax1.bar(df['Year'],df['Population Growth'],color='y')

#specify we want to share the same x-axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

#lineplot creation
ax2 = sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='Percent Growth', data=df,color='#C33E3E')


plt.show()
```

With this code I get the following graph:

[image: combo chart with bar chart and line chart]